# Filter The Entities by Linq

Tags: vb.net, linq

Here is my situation:

I need to bind this EntitySet to the Repeater.

The old way is:

```
repPackageProducts.DataSource = package.PackageProducts
repPackageProducts.DataBind()
```

Note: package is an Entity, PackageProducts is an EntitySet

Now, I need to filter this PackageProducts base on its own PackageProductPricingVars's column IsNew(True/False).

I use LINQ like this, but cannot add the Where statement:

```
Dim s = (From b In package.PackageProducts Select b.PackageProductPricingVars).Where...
```

I'm stuck at `.Where`. It not shows the column name of PackageProductPricingVars that I need to filter.

Please give me a hint.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1- Query Syntex:

```
Dim s = From p In package.PackageProducts _
        Where p.PackageProductPricingVars.IsNew = True _
        Select p.PackageProductPricingVars
```

2- Method Syntax:

```
Dim s = package.PackageProducts _
    .Where(function(p) p.PackageProductPricingVars.IsNew = True) _
    .Select(function(p) PackageProductPricingVars)
```